# Abstract view of how distinct queries are implemented in NoSQL

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am developing a system using Google Data-Store, where there's a Kind - Posts and which has 2 properties

```
1. message (string) 
2. hashtags (list)
```

I wanted to query the distinct hashtags with the number. For example 
say The posts are

```
  {
    {
      "message":"msg1",
      "tags":["abc","cde","efr"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg2",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efk"]
    },
    {
      "message":"msg3",
      "tags":["abc,"efgh","efr"]
    }
  }
```

The output should be

```
{
  "abc":3
  "cde":1
  "efk":1
  "efgh":2
  "efr":2
}
```

But in NoSQL implementation Data-store I can't directly query this. In order to query I have to load all the messages and find distinct queries. It will be a time-consuming event.

But I have seen a distinct function [db.collection.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) which I think might have optimize this problem. If It has to be done on any NoSQL what may be the optimum solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, projection queries with 'distinct on' will only return a single result per distinct value (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projection_queries).  It will not provide a count of each distinct value.   You'll need to do the count yourself, but you can use a projection query to save cost by only returning the tag values instead of the full entities.